# How to set ExtensibilityWindowSize to small in Lync 2013

Tags: extensibility, lync-2013

I developed the Lync conversation extension window to Lync 2013 client that used silverlight.

I want to resize the extension windows size and set the registry key "ExtensibilityWindowSize"=dword:00000000.
But the small size(dword:00000000) and medium size(dword:00000001) are same size and identity.

How can I set ExtensibilityWindowSize to small in Lync 2013 correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that size 0 and 1 are identical despite the advertised values on MSDN.

Source: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/12/lync-conversation-window-extension-cwe-sizes/

Comment: I have already referenced this site.Do you have the any other way to change the extension windows size except the registry setting?

Comment: Afraid not.  We were hoping that this was just a bug to be resolved in a client update but so far nothing.